# How to include globalconfig file into dotnet build call?

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net, editorconfig

I need to lower some custom analyzers severity from error to warning in my CI build. I prepared a proper .globalconfig file for this task. Now I need to make "dotnet build" call aware of this file. I created a CustomTargets.targets file:

```
<Project>
  <Target Name="MyTarget" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <RunCodeAnalysis>false</RunCodeAnalysis>
      <RunAnalyzersDuringBuild>true</RunAnalyzersDuringBuild>
      <ErrorLog>$(TestRootPath)$(TargetFileName).sarif.json</ErrorLog>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <GlobalAnalyzerConfigFiles Include="$(TestRootPath)\.globalconfig" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

My dotnet build call looks as follows:

```
dotnet build MySolution.sln /verbosity:minimal /p:Configuration=Debug /p:CustomAfterMicrosoftCommonTargets=%CCNetWorkingDirectory%\CustomTargets.targets /p:TestRootPath=%CCNetWorkingDirectory%
```

With the above configuration I still keep getting errors for analyzers that should have severity lowered to warning. My .globalconfig file is correct, because when used inside Visual Studio, I see only warnings reported. What do I miss?